# Solving real trigonometric integral with the residue theorem

Tags: definite-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I'm trying to find the solution to a definite integral using the Residue Theorem. I've currently found the poles of the complex function $f(z)$ but am unsure of how to classify those poles in order to apply the limit definition of the residue.

Of the poles, $2$ are within the unit circle in the complex plane but I'm unsure of the order of these poles. I'm evaluating the integral at the top of the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost done. I usually take a slightly different $f$:$$f(z)=\frac1z\cdot\frac1{1+\left(\frac{z+1/z}2\right)^2}=\frac{4 z}{z^4+6 z^2+1}.$$The roots of $z^4+6 z^2+1$ are, as you know, $\pm i\sqrt{3\pm2\sqrt2}$, of which only $\pm i\sqrt{3-2\sqrt2}$ have absolute value smaller than $1$. Since $z^4+6 z^2+1$ has degree four, each of these roots is a simple root and so it's a simple pole of $f$. And so\begin{align}\operatorname{res}_{z=\pm i\sqrt{3-2\sqrt2}}f(z)&=\frac{\pm4i\sqrt{3-2\sqrt2}}{4\left(\pm i\sqrt{3-2\sqrt2}\right)^3+12\left(\pm i\sqrt{3-2\sqrt2}\right)}\\&=\frac1{2\sqrt2}.\end{align}So, your integral is equal to$$2\pi\left(\frac1{2\sqrt2}+\frac1{2\sqrt2}\right)=\pi\sqrt2.$$

Comment: What formulation did you use to determine the residue?

Comment: This one:$$\operatorname{res}_{z=a}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\frac{f(a)}{g'(a)},$$which works whenever $g'(a)\ne0$.